# keeping track of time a user is actively using an android app

Tags: android

I am trying to find the best way to keep track of how much time a user spent on an android application (to report it to a server). I am only interested in tracking time where the user seems to use the app, so if it's in the background i shouldn't count that time for example.
I did some research and the only suggestion I found so far is using the onResume() and onPause() methods of activities to keep track of elapsed time between those 2 calls; I would probably need to do this in each activity of the application which doesn't seem to be a very elegant solution.
Is there another way, or better way to keep track of this time?

thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Nope not that I know of. I think you will have to end up with something like what you've mentioned. Be sure that you are correctly informing your users that you are collecting this information too. As a user if I found out that an app was collecting and transmitting that data without notifying me first(and maybe giving me the option to opt out) I would not be very pleased and would definitely not keep using it.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think that there's anything better. If all your activities extend `Activity`, then you can consolidate the code needed to track the time by having them extend your own custom `Activity` subclass and put all the tracking logic there. It might also help to have your own Application subclass and put the shared data structures there for keeping track of time.

Comment: Like Ted said, extend Activity, add the code to track the time between onResume() and onPause().  All your Activities should then extend this extended Activity.  It doesn't get a lot more elegant than that.

Comment: thanks everyone for all the helpful answers, I am implementing the onResume()/onPause() solution.